# using jquery's when for a callback on multiple ajax calls with _.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I saw some examples on wrapping ajax calls with jquery's when function.  As I'm just getting started with JS, I'm unsure on how to do this with a _.each.  All the examples were cases where they just created an array and wrapped it in jquery's when.  Right now, the code basically goes:

```
_.each(this.models, function (model) {
                model.fetch({
                    success: function (model, response) {
                        // do something                    },
```

How can I wrap this with jquery's when to get a callback when everything is finished?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var requests = _.map(this.models, function (model) {
        return model.fetch({
            success: function (model, response) {
            }
        });
});

//Working around the fact that array is not accepted
$.when.apply($, requests).then(function(){

});
```

Comment: I think that `$.when(requests)` really needs to be `$.when.apply($,requests)`, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @JayC yeah it looks like it still doesn't accept arrays :( what a shame

Comment: @Esailija Could you explain the $ parameter to the when jquery method?  I'm still pretty noob about to the web world.

Comment: @Crystal `.apply` is the only way to pass an array of arguments that become normal arguments in the receiving function.. so it's somewhat magical. The first argument isn't used in this case (the context) so it doesn't matter what I pass there. See docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: @Esailija Ah great, thanks!  One more quick question.  If I have an additional external call that has nothing to do with my models that, can I append that or insert that into the requests somehow?

Comment: @Crystal `requests.push(additionaljQXHR)` before you call `$.when`